# Slow gradle configuration phase due to SDK parsing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

In my 6-7s gradle configuration phase, 5s are spent on SDK parsing.
Log output:

```
Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
SDK initialized in 4625 ms
```

- Why do I have to spend time on every build to initialize an SDK even though I'm using a gradle daemon?
- The log suggests that caching should be possible, is there an option somewhere?
- Could I speed this up in any other way?

Comment: Maybe little more info? what SDK is it? full log?

Comment: The full log is 1500 lines long. It is just a normal gradle (multi-project) build. I guess the SDK is the android sdk, but I don't know for sure, because all I have are these log messages and their timestamps.

Comment: Anyway, to be hoest, 5 seconds in build time, is not something you should try to be fixing :D

Comment: In a build which takes under 10 seconds, spending half of the time in a step of which I don't know what it does seems just wrong. Also, with about 30 builds per hour, this adds up to several minutes. I agree that it is not a pressing matter, I just like to know what slows my builds down.

Comment: Interesting! Where is the Android SDK installed? Is it on a slow disk or network drive, by any chance?

Comment: @F43nd1r you'll be working at some point on large projects that take minutes to build, then the 5 seconds are going to be the least of your worries, I would say don't optimize for an issue that is not there. That's just my opinion.

Comment: @clownba0t installed on my local SSD drive, next to my windows installation

Comment: I just updated the post to clarify that I'm only talking about the configuration phase, the build itself is already optimized as far as possible.